# How to update hashmap data in ElasticSearch using API Update (version 5) in Java?

Tags: java, elasticsearch-api

I am trying to update data in Elastic Search Server using the following Code.

1) I have used the following to insert the data in elastic search.

```
 HashMap<String, String> hmExtra = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
 hmExtra.put("One", "1");
 hmExtra.put("Two", "2");


 HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
 data.put("case_name","Test");
 data.put("case_extra",hmExtra);


 IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest("org-8").type("Group").source(data);

 IndexResponse response = client.index(indexRequest, header);
```

When I queried the Elastic search using the key, the got back the following result:

```
 {
   "_index": "org-8",
   "_type": "Group",
   "_id": "AW4gTZwCAdqCPewR2ukW",
   "_version": 2,
   "found": true,
   "_source": {
     "case_name","Test",
     "case_extra": {
       "One": "1",
       "Two": "2"
     }
   }
 }
```

After the insertion of data(HashMap) it is inserted successfully into search.

2) Trying to update the same.

After that when I tried to update the case_extra with below code. The search query was displaying the existing values.

```
 HashMap<String, String> hmExtra = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
 hmExtra.put("One", "9");

HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
 data.put("case_name","Test2");
data.put("case_extra",hmExtra);


UpdateRequest request = new UpdateRequest("org-8", "Group", "AW4gTZwCAdqCPewR2ukW").doc(data);
UpdateResponse updateResponse = client.update(request);
```

Result:

```
 {
   "_index": "org-8",
   "_type": "Group",
   "_id": "AW4gTZwCAdqCPewR2ukW",
   "_version": 2,
   "found": true,
   "_source": {
     "case_name","Test2",
     "case_extra": {
       "One": "9",
       "Two": "2"
     }
   }
 }
```

Based on the above result, Key 'Two' was not removed from the case_extra.

I need help to use Api Update in elasticsearch, I tried the above code and the problem is the second value of the HashMap removed from case_extra.

Thanks in Advance.

**Update**

Here is the code which I have tried.

Before update request, the document looks like below:

```
{
  "_index": "org-8",
  "_type": "Group",
  "_id": "AW4cWb2g90EOmg5E-TFl",
  "_version": 22,
  "found": true,
  "_source": {
    "case_name": "Test1",
    "case_extra": {
      "One": "1",
      "Two": "2"
    }
  }
}
```

Update Request code which is same as Garvit Khamesra gave in his answer:

```
    RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(
            RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 9200,"http")));

    HashMap<String, String> hmExtra1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    hmExtra1.put("One", "9");

    Map<String, Object> data1 = new HashMap<>();
    data1.put("case_extra",hmExtra1);
    data1.put("case_name", "Test2");

    Map<String, Object> parameters = Collections.singletonMap("val", data1);

    UpdateRequest request = new UpdateRequest("org-8", "Group", "AW4cWb2g90EOmg5E-TFl");

    Script script = new Script(ScriptType.INLINE, "painless",
                               "ctx._source = params.val", parameters);
    request.script(script);

    try {
        UpdateResponse updateResponse = client.update(request);
        System.out.println(updateResponse.getGetResult().sourceAsString());
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

After I ran the above code, the error that I received is below:

```
ElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch exception [type=illegal_argument_exception, reason=[script] unknown field [source], parser not found]]
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.BytesRestResponse.errorFromXContent(BytesRestResponse.java:177)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:618)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseResponseException(RestHighLevelClient.java:594)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:501)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:474)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.update(RestHighLevelClient.java:353)
    at com.goclockwork.ontracksearchengine.test.UpdateSearchTest.main(UpdateSearchTest.java:54)
    Suppressed: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [POST], host [http://localhost:9200], URI [/org-8/Group/AW4cWb2g90EOmg5E-TFl/_update?timeout=1m], status line [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request]
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"[script] unknown field [source], parser not found"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"[script] unknown field [source], parser not found"},"status":400}
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$1.completed(RestClient.java:357)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$1.completed(RestClient.java:346)
        at org.apache.http.concurrent.BasicFuture.completed(BasicFuture.java:119)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.responseCompleted(DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.java:177)
        at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.processResponse(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:436)
        at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.inputReady(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:326)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:265)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:81)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:39)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:114)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Dependency which I am using as below:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.3</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying is a partial update method of elastic search. We need to use script update.

```
    RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(
            RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 9200,"http")));

    HashMap<String, String> hmExtra1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    hmExtra1.put("One", "9");

    Map<String, HashMap<String, String>> data1 = new HashMap<>();
    data1.put("case_extra",hmExtra1);

    Map<String, Object> parameters = singletonMap("val", data1);

    UpdateRequest request = new UpdateRequest("org-8", "Group", "CBCyJm4BWKXF8n_XGsze");

    Script script = new Script(ScriptType.INLINE, "painless",
                               "ctx._source = params.val", parameters);
    request.script(script);

    UpdateResponse updateResponse = client.update(request);
```

Now the document will become

```
{"_index":"org-8","_type":"Group","_id":"CBCyJm4BWKXF8n_XGsze","_version":5,"found":true,"_source":{"case_extra":{"One":"9"}}}
```

Here is documentation -
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-document-update.html

Comment: I already went through this link, but it is quite different from what I want. I have updated my question. please check.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Can you run that and check?

Comment: I don't see get() method in line 'client.update(updateRequest).get();'

Comment: Can you tell me the exact version of elastic search you are using?

Comment: The client object that I am using is RestHighLevelClient. Please tell me which client object reference do you want me to use.

Comment: The version that I am using is 6.2.1

Comment: I have tried the code which you posted. I don't see get() method. I need to know what is the client object type your code is using. The client object type that I am using is RestHighLevelClient.

Comment: TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
        .addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));

Comment: I have updated the answer. Sorry for the confusion and also the answer is for high-level rest client.

Comment: With your code, I am getting back the error saying "ElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch exception [type=illegal_argument_exception, reason=[script] unknown field [source], parser not found]]"

Comment: I have updated the answer and tried the same code. it is working as expected.

Comment: I have updated the code accordingly but still getting the same error. "ElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch exception [type=illegal_argument_exception, reason=[script] unknown field [source], parser not found]]"

Comment: Can you please get the data for http://localhost:9200/org-8/Group/CBCyJm4BWKXF8n_XGsze and paste it in your answer.

Comment: Can you share your code ad dependencies you are using? Or you got the answer?

Comment: I have updated the question with the code and dependencies. Please check.

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

In ES 7.9 this also works using UpdateByQueryRequest

> Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
>
> ```
>   UpdateByQueryRequest updateByQueryRequest = new UpdateByQueryRequest("indexName");
>   updateByQueryRequest.setConflicts("proceed");
>   updateByQueryRequest.setQuery(new TermQueryBuilder("_id", documentId));
>   Script script = new Script(ScriptType.INLINE, "painless",
>           "ctx._source = params", map);
>   updateByQueryRequest.setScript(script);
> ```